# Postman overwrites environment variable prior to sending request

Tags: environment-variables, postman

I am sending a GET request that uses an environment variable used for an access token.

Prior to sending the request, I see that the variable has the correct value.
After sending, the request gets an Unauthorized response.  I look at the environment variable and see that it's now "undefined".

I am not setting this variable in any way with this request.  It's just a simple GET.  I have checked various code outputs before sending the request and they all show valid values for the token.  However once the I sent the GET request, the values are undefined.

Any ideas???

Comment: Can you post images of what you're seeing, it will help people to understand the problem more. Something must be in the Collection or sub folder pre-request / tests for that to be changing the environment variable. It doesn't do it on it's own.